# how to remove gap between text and image when im using android:drawableLeft

Tags: android, xamarin

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:background="#ffffff">
          <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sorttxt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.995"
                android:text="Sort"
                android:textSize="17dp"       
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="#25a65b"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/leftImagesort"
                android:gravity="center"        
                />
           <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_5"
                android:layout_weight="0.01" />
         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/filtertxt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.995"
                android:text="Sort"
                android:textSize="17dp"       
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="#25a65b"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/leftImagefilter"
                android:gravity="center"

                />
```

I am using above code but wants to remove gap between image and text i have used android:drawableLeft to insert image in textview

right now i am getting output shown in image

[image: right now i am getting output shown in image]

Comment: make `textview` width `wrap_content` also remove gravity attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set attribute `android:gravity="left"` instead of `android:gravity="center"` in both `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drawable left for showing image and you want to remove gap between image and text then you need to use `android:drawablePadding="-20dp"`. you need to give drawablePadding in minus.

You can use like :

```
android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

set `drawablePadding="0dp"` and `android:gravity="left|center"`